# File renamed successfully but MediaStore returns the same file name

Tags: android, mediastore

I am building a simple video player application. I wanted to add a feature to rename video files from the app.

I am getting all the video files from `MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")` with a filter of  `MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE LIKE "video%"` instead of `MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` directly because this skipped some of the files that I wanted to be there.

I got the following Java code that renames a file:

```
file.renameTo(File(file.parent, "video.mkv"))
```

It worked successfully and there was no problem with this.

**How did I know that it was renamed?**
I had another video player application so I checked if the file was renamed and the weird thing was, it was renamed there.

But when I again queried `MediaStore` it was not updated there, it gave the same file name again.
And after some browsing, I got to know that I need to update `MediaStore` too.

So if `MediaStore` is not updated, then how does that application know that the file was renamed?
Also, I don't know if this is important but just to mention here, it was not an in-built application so there is no chance of having any special permissions to access any "special" database.

So I don't think updating `MediaStore` is really necessary to rename a file. 
**Is there any other way of doing this?**

Thanks

Comment: What Android version is used? On older Android version you had to inform the MediaStore database that there was a file change.

Comment: @Robert I tested it on Pie